# MultiAutoCompleteTextView not showing keyboard suggestions

Tags: android, android-layout, multiautocompletetextview

I'm using `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` in my app. It's an awesome control in Android API. But there are a few issues I'm facing. One, the most annoying is, that on my Nexus 5, it doesnot shows keyboard suggestions. On Xperia Z, shows keyboard suggestions though. Unable to find the cause. Can anybody help/guide me about it? Here the XML of my `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`.

```
<MultiAutoCompleteTextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:hint="Post a question, idea or update"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:textColorHint="#9e9e9e"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@null" />
```

Comment: My Samsung S4 shows keyboard suggestions. If i switch off predictive text ( Settings/Mydevice/Language and input/Predictive text) keyboard suggestions do not show. Try https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8XnkrK_2Q1A

Comment: I've `EditText` in some of my views, and they show suggestions normally. So I think, it has nothing to do with the device settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have looked into the source code and found this in `AutoCompleteTextView`

```
    // Always turn on the auto complete input type flag, since it
    // makes no sense to use this widget without it.
    int inputType = getInputType();
    if ((inputType&EditorInfo.TYPE_MASK_CLASS)
            == EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT) {
        inputType |= EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_COMPLETE;
        setRawInputType(inputType);
    }
```

And in the javaDoc page of the `InputType`, `TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_COMPLETE` defined as.

> Flag for TYPE_CLASS_TEXT: the text editor (which means the application) is performing auto-completion of the text being entered based on its own semantics, which it will present to the user as they type.

It means that you have your own semantics for completion, which means that it is logical for the keyboard to disable its suggestions.

I think when you change the inputType with `setInputType()` method programatically you can disable this behaviour and get the keyboard suggestions.

You can try this:

```
mAutoCompletetextView.setInputType(EditText.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | EditText.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT);
```